# Moving Magento Blocks Around. Magento 1.7.X

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks

I am using Magento 1.7.x Community Edition. I have a static block I created called Custom Tab and I wanted to have that appear right below the Additional Information area. Right now it goes like this:

Located on a Product Page in Magento

1. Product Description Area
2. Additional Information Area (Called Product Specs, I created additional attributes)
3. Product Tags Area
4. And then the Custom Tab Area

You can find there actual site here: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/archilume-collection/e100-series/e100w24v.html

Is there a way to have Custom Tab show right below the Additional Information Area then have Product Tags right below it?

If so can you please describe what pages I have to modify in Magento to have this done?

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help me? This should be pretty easy to do just need a little help!

Comment: No body knows how to move simple block in magento from below and item to on top?

Answer (score 2):

In the default theme the description, additional information and tags blocks are added using this xml markup:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
</block>
```

This means that each block is added as a child to `detailed_info` block. Unfortunately the method used `addToParentGroup` does not accept a parameter for the position of the block, so the blocks are added as they are encountered in the xml files. Most probably your layout file is loaded last so your block is shown last.
What you can do is to add your block in the `catalog.xml` file of your theme right below

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
</block>
```

This way you are sure that is added exactly after the attributes block.