# how to position block within category page?

Tags: blocks

I am calling a block into a category page using the following code:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="cms/block" name="my-grid" as="my-grid" before="-">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>my-grid</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

This calls in a block (which loads a phtml code) and places it at the top of the category page.

How can I move it down, so it is just below the category header title? So essentially, just one line lower in the page > but not sure how to control that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

`<reference name="content">
<block type="cms/block" name="my-grid" as="my-grid" before="block-name">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>my-grid</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>`

where block-name is the block to be used as reference. 
Tags before and after applies for this. Some documentation about this [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts).

Comment: ok, thanks. By enabling bloock name tips, I can see that its called "Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View". However, I want my block to be 'in' in that block itself.

This block is the category header, followed by the text in the category description field.

I want my new block to go between the category header and category description.

Sounds like a problem?

Comment: That is not the name you wanted. That is the class of the block instead of the name. The name is in the XML file. Probably he name of the block you are looking for is in catalog.xml since you are looking a category page by the class you saw.

Comment: Hi Folks, I still didn't work this out. I am looking for it to be inserted in the line before the Product Description is pumped out. I've tried using before="product.description" but no go :(

Comment: Check the name of that block and replace product.description for the one you find.

Comment: ok, but I don't get how to check for that block. There are no blocks for those sections. They come from the view.phtml page, there you can see the description being called via:<?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?> etc ... but in the catalog.xml there is nothing. :(

Comment: Try to put it programatically there instead of using a layout. It might be easier for this case.

Comment: yeah, someone else seems to have a similar issue here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/moving-magento-blocks-around

Comment: It looks to me like with `<reference name="content">` you are targeting the wrong block to be able to place your block inside the correct block. Try targeting `<reference name="category.products">` which is using the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` template.